# Issue in linking Static Library in CMake [linux]

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mingw

I am using pre-built static libraries in the project.
I am getting issue in linking. Details as follows.

cmake

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib)
add_executable(main isotp_send.c)

target_link_libraries(main -static-libgcc -static dl
                        pthread
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libIsoTp.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libBL.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libCanTp.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libDcm.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libEa.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libFls.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libNvM.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libSd.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libSRec.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libCanLib.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libCom.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libDem.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libEep.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libOsekNm.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libSoAd.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libStdBit.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libCanNm.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libCrc.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libDoIP.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libFee.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libLoader.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libRingBuffer.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libSomeIp.a
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/lib/libStdTimer.a
                    

                      )
```

While building am facing issues. The following log

```
[  9%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/isotp_send.c.o
[ 18%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/Can.c.o
[ 27%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/Can_Lcfg.c.o
[ 36%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/critical.c.o
[ 45%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/Dem_Stub.c.o
[ 54%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/EepAc.c.o
[ 63%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/Flash.c.o
[ 72%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/FlsAc.c.o
[ 81%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/Key.c.o
[ 90%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/simulator.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable main
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libIsoTp.a(isotp_can.o):isotp_can.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libIsoTp.a(isotp_can.o):isotp_can.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libIsoTp.a(isotp_can.o):isotp_can.c:(.text+0x45f): undefined reference to `sem_init'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libIsoTp.a(Dcm_Cfg.o):Dcm_Cfg.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libIsoTp.a(Dcm_Cfg.o):Dcm_Cfg.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanTp.a(CanTp.o):CanTp.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanTp.a(CanTp.o):CanTp.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libDcm.a(Dcm.o):Dcm.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libDcm.a(Dcm.o):Dcm.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libDcm.a(Dcm_Dsd.o):Dcm_Dsd.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libDcm.a(Dcm_Dsd.o):Dcm_Dsd.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libDcm.a(Dcm_Dsl.o):Dcm_Dsl.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libDcm.a(Dcm_Dsl.o):Dcm_Dsl.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(canlib.o):canlib.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(canlib.o):canlib.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(canlib.o):canlib.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(canlib.o):canlib.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `__imp__time64'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(canlib.o):canlib.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `__imp__localtime64'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(canlib.o):canlib.c:(.text+0xd3b): undefined reference to `__imp_isprint'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(peak_can.o):peak_can.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(peak_can.o):peak_can.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(peak_can.o):peak_can.c:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `CAN_Initialize'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(peak_can.o):peak_can.c:(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(peak_can.o):peak_can.c:(.text+0x3a8): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(peak_can.o):peak_can.c:(.text+0x433): undefined reference to `CAN_Write'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(peak_can.o):peak_can.c:(.text+0x5c7): undefined reference to `CAN_Read'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `__imp_inet_addr'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x1ed): undefined reference to `__imp_htons'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x20d): undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `__imp_connect'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x2a3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x2c5): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x2f0): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to `__imp_ioctlsocket'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x380): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x4af): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x549): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x585): undefined reference to `__imp_send'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x6cf): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x756): undefined reference to `__imp_recvfrom'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x7c2): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(simulator_can.o):simulator_can.c:(.text+0x804): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `__mingw_vsscanf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `__mingw_vsprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `__imp_strncpy_s'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `__imp_strncpy_s'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0x67c): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0x79d): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(vxl_can.o):vxl_can.c:(.text+0xbcd): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x1cb): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x275): more undefined references to `dlsym' follow
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x734): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(zlg_can.o):zlg_can.c:(.text+0x817): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `__imp_LoadLibraryA'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `__imp_GetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `__imp_GetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `__imp_GetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `__imp_GetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `__imp_GetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text+0x186): more undefined references to `__imp_GetProcAddress' follow
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text+0x2b15): undefined reference to `__imp_FreeLibrary'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libStdTimer.a(std_timer.o):std_timer.c:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text$_Z6printfPKcz[_Z6printfPKcz]+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libCanLib.a(xlLoadlib.o):xlLoadlib.cpp:(.text$_Z6printfPKcz[_Z6printfPKcz]+0x43): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:243: main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

For the reference, I am using Ubuntu 20.0 and I have reinstalled Mingw as suggested by other answers. Also, dl library linking is right in target_link_directories.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Library order matters, especially for static linking.  Since some of the error messages are related to not finding functions from libdl, definitely move that library after all the locally-built libs.

Most of the the other errors seem to be associated with internal functions from the MinGW standard library and GCC builds, so they are probably associated with the `-static-libgcc` option.  You should be able to verify that by removing that option.  You might be able to fix it without removing the option by moving that option to the end, but you shouldn't need it in the first place because you are performing an overall `-static` link.

Additionally, do not link libpthread.  If yours is a pthreads program then add `-pthread` to the C compilation flags and to the linker flags (not the same thing as specifying `-lpthread` among the link libraries).

HOWEVER, there is something very fishy here.  You are linking libdl into your statically-linked executable, but the functions it provides are interfaces to the dynamic linker, which is not applicable to static binaries.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried to keep the dl library at last as you suggested but still facing the issue. Some functions in static libraries are depending on ptherad but I do not have the source file, all I have .a file which I am trying to use. I have moved -static-libgcc to last, still no changes in the log. Is there something I might be missing here?

Comment: @ashwinvijaykumar, in addition to the issues I already described -- and do not ignore the last paragraph of this answer -- It is suspicious that you have tagged both [linux] and [mingw].  These are different environments.  I didn't think that too relevant until you said you don't have source.  From the link errors, at least some of the libraries must have been built with MinGW.  If you are trying to link such libraries into an executable that you are building on Linux then that's simply not going to work.